# Unable to figure out how to replace a tag in xml

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

Need help to figure out correct regex for replacing xml tag with contents of a file.

Tried basic things like escaping special characters but no luck. Open to using something else other than sed.

config.txt

```
    <localReplications/>
```

replace-with-config.txt

```
    <localReplications>
        <localReplication>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <cronExp>0 0 /5 * * ?</cronExp>
            <syncDeletes>true</syncDeletes>
            <syncProperties>true</syncProperties>
            <repoKey>some-repo-key</repoKey>
            <url>https://foo.bar/random</url>
            <socketTimeoutMillis>15000</socketTimeoutMillis>
            <username>foo</username>
            <password>bar</password>
            <enableEventReplication>true</enableEventReplication>
            <syncStatistics>false</syncStatistics>
        </localReplication>
    </localReplications>
```

`<localReplications/>` tag is part of really complicated xml file. I expect `<localReplications/>` to be replaced with contents in replace-with-config.txt

Comment: Do not use regex to parse and/or modify XML.  Use a real XML parser, in your case an XSLT processor would be able to do exactly what you need.  Perl has XSLT bindings, as described several places including [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-cookbook/0596003722/ch12s16.html)

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use XML::LibXML qw();
my $config = XML::LibXML
    ->load_xml(location => 'config.txt');
my $replace = (XML::LibXML
    ->load_xml(location => 'replace-with-config.txt')
    ->findnodes('//localReplications')
)[0];
for my $local_replications (
    $config->findnodes('//localReplications')
) {
    # $local_replications->replaceNode($replace);
    # this fails with HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR,
    # so do it in two steps instead
    $local_replications->addSibling($replace);
    $local_replications->unbindNode;
}
print $config->toString;
```